# Vue component's button callback: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

Using Vue3+typescript, I'm trying to use a library called [gtag-vue](https://matteo-gabriele.gitbook.io/vue-gtag/) to send google analytics events to my account.

The idea is that in a Vue component, when the user clicks a div, I'll send a custom event, `myCustomEvent`.

```
<template>
    <div v-on:click="displayWhatever(index)">SOME CONTENT HERE</div>
</template>
```

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { event } from 'vue-gtag'

let selected = ref(-1);

const myComputedVar = computed(() => {
  return someVar.slice(//Some stuff here that returns a proper array with no errors);
}

function displayWhatever(this: any, index: number): void {
  selected.value = index;
  event('myCustomEvent', {
    value1: this.myComputedVar[index].value1,
    value2: this.myComputedVar[index].value2
  })
}
</script>
```

Whenever I use it in development, by running `npm run dev` it works perfectly! But when I do `npm run build`, with no errors and upload it, I get this error in the Javascript console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'myComputedVar')
    at y (index-39a6e75d.js:1535:23997)
    at onClick (index-39a6e75d.js:1535:25733)
    at xn (index-39a6e75d.js:1:13194)
    at cr (index-39a6e75d.js:1:13273)
    at HTMLDivElement.r (index-39a6e75d.js:1:56693)
```

So it looks like `this` is not correctly set up in the production build. But I really can't understand why. I have tried other methods, like removing the `this` from the function, but then I get compile errors when doing `npm run build`.

I'm using Vite by the way, in case it makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `this` (that refers to component instance as in options API) in script setup syntax, you should use `computedVar.value` instead of `this.computedVar` :

```js
function displayWhatever( index: number): void {
  selected.value = index;
  event('myCustomEvent', {
    value1: myComputedVar.value[index].value1,
    value2: myComputedVar.value[index].value2
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a setup (composition api), You won't need `this` keyword. Also, modify the `displayWhatever` function parameter. It should accept only one parameter, Hence remove `this`.

The value of computed property will be kept in a `value` property of the created reference. Hence, you should access it by using `.value` instead of `this.`

```
function displayWhatever(index: number): void {
  selected.value = index;
  event('myCustomEvent', {
    value1: myComputedVar.value[index].value1,
    value2: myComputedVar.value[index].value2
  })
}
```